# How do I target unknown <div>s from the CSS

Tags: html, css, django

how do you add `:target {opacity: 1}` onto the `href"#pop{{user.user_id}}"` below?
the `user_id` is unknown until the page generates

The for loop as follows;

```
{% for user in pull %}
    <a href="#pop{{user.user_id}}">Link: {{user.user_name}} {{ user.user_id }}</a>

    <div style="opacity:0" id="pop{{user.user_id}}">
                {{ user.info }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Which looks like this after its translated onto a web page from Django.

```
<a href="#pop10">Link: tom 10</a>

<div style="opacity:0" id="pop10">
this is my info
</div>

<a href="#pop8">Link: ann 8</a>

<div style="opacity:0" id="pop8">
i am an apple
</div>

<a href="#pop3">Link: mike 3</a>

<div style="opacity:0" id="pop3">
i like pears
</div>
```

Comment: You're approaching this completely the wrong way. The way to make tabs appear and disappear depending on a button click is to get your JS to add and remove a class to the relevant div.

Comment: yeah but even if you use JS or CSS, the question is how do you target, id="pop{{user.user_id}},

Comment: But the point is in your Javascript you know the ID, because it's in the href you clicked on.

Comment: no, in the example above you are clicking on <a> links that links to #pop10 etc generated by the for loop, you can't whack the #pop{{user.user_id}} into the JS, because the JS isn't iterating through a loop to pull out each id, so the JS wouldn't know each <div> seperately

Comment: But it doesn't have to! You have a generic click method, and that can get the value of `$this.attr('href')` (assuming you're using jQuery) then use that to get the target and add the class.

Comment: @SprigMendle: Could you please provide a clear problem statement, and what you're looking to achieve. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand exactly what you're looking to achieve?

Comment: @jbutler483 okay I will re-write the question, thankyou

Comment: @Sprig Tbh I can hardly imagine Daniel actually getting angry, but the added emphasis is probably because you're completely missing the point. The `<a>` tag, which is created in the loop, points to the right div. It's easy to convert the `href` which points to `#pop3` to the actual div `#pop3`, especially with jQuery. Create an `onClick` method, and the targeted div will simply be `$($this.attr('href'))`, no matter which link is clicked. Thus, you don't have to know the actual id in your javascript when you're writing the code, only when it's executed, and at that time it's freely available.

Answer (score 0):

if the styles for all of them are same then you can add a class in the loop for each div and anchor and then add style to these anchors and divs which have this added class. If you want different styles for these divs and anchors then you need to have the id's .Hope it helps

```
{% for user in pull %}
    <a class="styled_class" href="#pop{{user.user_id}}">Link: {{user.user_name}} {{ user.user_id }}</a>

    <div class="styled_div" style="opacity:0" id="pop{{user.user_id}}">
                {{ user.info }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after a lot of thinking i figured it out by myself, all you need to do is make a style tag in the same template which is encased in the same for loop to generate the individual unique css Ids pointing to each div

```
<style type="text/css">
 {% for i in pull %}
        #pop{{i.user_id}}:target {
            opacity: 1;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        #pop{{i.user_id}} {
            width: 58.8em;
            min-height: 10em;
            background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #FFA500;
            top: 9em;
            border-radius: 16px;
            opacity: 0;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: -1;
            transition: opacity 1s ease 0s, z-index 1s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 1, 0) 0s;
            max-height: 34em;
            padding: 1em;
            margin-left: 1em;
        }

        #pop_close{{i.user_id}}:target {
            opacity: 0;
            z-index: -1;
        }
    {% endfor %}
</style>
```